# What are the differences between running "command &" and "command -D"

Tags: shell, command-line, background-process, daemon

I initially thought `command &` was the command to 'daemonize' a command, but it turns out `command -D` is the proper command. What exactly does `command &` do? I can't find anything on that specific option anywhere, and would like to know if it has a name and just the technical specifics on it

Comment: The term you're looking for is 'background'.  From the [`bash` manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash): "If a command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell executes the  command  in the background in a subshell."

Answer (score 4):

I was slightly confused at first as `command` is a shell built-in command (it executes a utility as a command and not as, say, a shell function if such a function happened to exist).

You use

```
$ utility &
```

to start `utility` as an asynchronous process (background process/job).

From the `bash` manual:

> If a command is terminated by the control operator `&`, the shell
>          executes the command in the background in a subshell.  The shell does
>          not wait for the command to finish, and the return status is 0.

From the `dash` manual:

> If a command is terminated by the control operator ampersand (`&`), the
>        shell executes the command asynchronously -- that is, the shell does not
>        wait for the command to finish before executing the next command.
>
> The format for running a command in background is:
>
> ```
> command1 & [command2 & ...]
> ```

(this happens to be identical to [the POSIX description of `&`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03_02))

Some utilities, usually daemons, may have flags that makes them go into the background and `-D` may be a common flag for these to use, but I've also often seen `--daemon` or `-d`.  Sometimes `-d` (or whatever flag) *prevents* the utility to background itself, such as `sshd -d` which prevents the SSH daemon process from backgrounding itself and instead makes it run as a foreground process and send all log output to standard output rather than to `syslog` (the `-d` flag stands for "debug" here).

However, there is no standard for these flags and each utility that supports these operations may implement them through different flags. You need to read the manual for the particular utility that you are dealing with.